# SplashScreen using PNG image leads to Android.Views.InflateException followed by OutOfMemory

Tags: android, xamarin.android, out-of-memory, inflate-exception

*I watched [Google IO 2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) conference, read almost every post about OutOfMemory Exception and InflateException, no luck, I cannot find any answer that solve my problem.*

How can I properly clear memory from a layout containing a background image? I feel like if the InflateException followed by OutOfMemory are related because that background image is not cleared properly.

So I'm getting :

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error
>   inflating class

followed by :

> Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Which I'm pretty sure is caused by my background image.

I simplified my code to narrow the problem as much as possible.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
  <activity />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" parent="android:Theme"/>
</manifest>
```

I added `parent="android:Theme"` which was suppose to fix the issue, no success.

**SplashScreen.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SplashScreenView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" />
```

splash is a .png image located in my drawable folder.

**SplashScreenActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "My splash screen", MainLauncher = true)]
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
        StartNextActivity();
    }

    private void StartNextActivity()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SplashScreenActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
    }

    public override void Finish()
    {
        base.Finish();
        var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SplashScreenView);

        view.Background.SetCallback(null);
        view.Background.Dispose();
        view.DestroyDrawingCache();
        Resources.FlushLayoutCache();
    }
}
```

First I do load the `SplashScreenActivity` continuously, this is intentional to make the errors happen sooner.

As you can see, I tried several things to clear the Background image, setting flags or explicitly trying to dispose it.

On the first load I get those messages, which seems to be ok since it is loading the image :

```
07-18 12:14:22.472 I/dalvikvm-heap(30085): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.600MB for 2949136-byte allocation 
07-18 12:14:22.522 D/dalvikvm(30085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 76K, 7% free 9432K/10119K, paused 2ms+1ms
```

However, it keep growing up until I consume all the device available memory :

```
07-18 12:12:17.852 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.605MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:17.852 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 1% free 65064K/65543K, paused 338ms
07-18 12:12:17.852 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1576-byte allocation
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.604MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:18.212 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 1% free 65064K/65543K, paused 362ms
07-18 12:12:18.212 E/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Out of memory on a 1576-byte allocation.
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a45460 self=0xb068a0
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | sysTid=18665 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074517128
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | schedstat=( 71462466000 19081532000 88403 ) utm=6360 stm=786 core=0
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedStyledAttributes(Resources.java:~2193)
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.content.res.Resources.access$000(Resources.java:71)
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1260)
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:364)
07-18 12:12:18.212 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2746)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2707)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2767)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:247)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:30)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:18.222 I/dalvikvm(18665): 
07-18 12:12:18.972 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.623MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:18.972 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 1% free 65082K/65543K, paused 341ms
07-18 12:12:18.982 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1402-byte allocation
07-18 12:12:19.332 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.623MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:19.332 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 1% free 65082K/65543K, paused 358ms
07-18 12:12:19.332 E/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Out of memory on a 1402-byte allocation.
07-18 12:12:19.332 I/dalvikvm(18665): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-18 12:12:19.332 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a45460 self=0xb068a0
07-18 12:12:19.332 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | sysTid=18665 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074517128
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | schedstat=( 72173821000 19107690000 88644 ) utm=6429 stm=788 core=0
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~94)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:623)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:601)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:579)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:660)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:722)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:329)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:305)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:30)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:19.342 I/dalvikvm(18665): 
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>

07-18 12:12:24.902 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.644MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:24.902 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 1% free 65105K/65543K, paused 377ms
07-18 12:12:24.902 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1402-byte allocation
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.644MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:25.242 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 65105K/65543K, paused 345ms
07-18 12:12:25.242 E/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Out of memory on a 1402-byte allocation.
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a45460 self=0xb068a0
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | sysTid=18665 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074517128
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | schedstat=( 72950645000 19154453000 88901 ) utm=6504 stm=791 core=0
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~94)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:623)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:601)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:579)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:660)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:722)
07-18 12:12:25.242 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:329)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:305)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:30)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:25.252 I/dalvikvm(18665): 
07-18 12:12:26.042 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.654MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:26.042 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 1% free 65114K/65543K, paused 395ms
07-18 12:12:26.042 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1126-byte allocation
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Clamp target GC heap from 68.654MB to 64.000MB
07-18 12:12:26.392 D/dalvikvm(18665): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 65114K/65543K, paused 344ms
07-18 12:12:26.392 E/dalvikvm-heap(18665): Out of memory on a 1126-byte allocation.
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a45460 self=0xb068a0
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | sysTid=18665 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074517128
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   | schedstat=( 73695992000 19195168000 89137 ) utm=6574 stm=795 core=0
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~94)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:623)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:601)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:579)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:660)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:722)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:329)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:305)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at myFirstApp.android.activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:30)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 12:12:26.392 I/dalvikvm(18665): 
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError:
```

### Additional information

The image is full screen and is the perfect size for this device (I mean that we don't want to shrink it). 1024x720, 24 bits, not Alpha and it takes 487KB on my disk, but obviously, when Android loads it, it seems to be around 10 MB.

I'm running the code on a Nabi2 tablet, model : NABI2-NV7A which is running Android version 4.0.4 along with Kernel version 3.1.10-00275-g3a4f8c1.

Also note that in Visual Studio in my Application Properties, I am targetting those Android versions:

[image: Application Properties Android Target]

Comment: How big is the splash image? Perhaps its worth trimming the image to only the content, aligning it in the center and changing the background color of the view?

Comment: @jimmithy Info updated in the last section called Additional Information.

Comment: Arent you having a loop here? `StartNextActivity` starts a `SplashScreenActivity` and this will keep on happening over and over again until you run out of memory...

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, that's what I mentioned, I use a loop to reproduce the problem that takes more time to occurs in the normal course of my application. However, in both case when the previous activity finish, the background image data doesn't seems to get cleared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found a way to do this without throwing these errors.

Instead of creating a `Layout` with the Splash Screen, I created a theme, since in your case it is simply an image anyways:

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/kitten</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then I created an Activity like this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

namespace SplashScreenSample
{
    [Activity(Label = "Splushy Splushy", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/SplashTheme")]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle b)
        {
            base.OnCreate(b);
            StartNextActivity();
        }

        private void StartNextActivity()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SplashActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
            StartActivity(intent);
            Finish();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running this on my phone for 10 minutes or so, without any crash with an image of 1600x1200 of a nice kitten.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is way more viable than the one I found. I also posted a solution that was working pretty well except for my SplashScreen. I'd be curious to see what you think of it. With your solution (combined with mine for my other activities) I'm confident that on a normal use of my App, the memory problem should not occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that helped, but never as much as [Cheesebaron's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745356/62921).

In both cases, it end up crashing.

- Cheesebaron's solution crashes after : 14 minutes
- Mine crashes after 3 minutes 28 sec.

Since I'm looping intensively to push the device to its limit, Cheesebaron's solution is surely viable.

In my case, instead of setting `android:background="@drawable/splash"`, I removed that entry and used a `private Bitmap` field in my activity which I then load and pass it to the background drawable.

```
private Bitmap _bitmapRef;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);        
    var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SplashScreenView);

    _bitmapRef = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.splash, new BitmapFactory.Options
                                                                      {
                                                                          InPurgeable = true,
                                                                          InInputShareable = true
                                                                      });
    view.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Resources, _bitmapRef));
    StartNextActivity();
}
```

Then, on the `OnDestroy` call, I override it to explicitly recycle the bitmap.

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
   base.OnDestroy();

   if (null != _bitmapRef && !_bitmapRef.IsRecycled)
   {
        _bitmapRef.Recycle();
        _bitmapRef = null;
    }
}
```

It seems to me like if Android have problems when the Bitmap is created at the Activity level.

I have another activities in which I load bitmaps in a list object to display them on screen. The list object is at the Activity level and the bitmaps are inside the list.

In that case, the memory seems to be handled properly when I use the above solution. I don't even have to call recycle on the bitmaps inside the list.

But for the SplashScreen, that solution doesn't seems to be enough.

Comment: Actually you can dispose of the `Bitmap` right after you have assigned it to the `ImageView`, the image will still be there on the Java side, and will get disposed of eventually when it is not displayed anymore. So you can simply surround your fetching of the `Bitmap` in a `using` statement.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Unfortunately, when I do this the image is never displayed. It is if I do not call `bitmapRef.recycle` inside the `using(...)` clause though, but then I got weird messages `mmap failed for imageref_ashmem size=2949120 err=12` followed by `mmap(0,579525) failed: Out of memory and crashes with Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-master/294d4619/source/mono/mono/mini/‌​mini.c:3986, condition code not met. Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.`